# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when trying to drag and drop between two WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have made a WPF application that allows drag and drop of instances of a class I made (`FakeNodeViewModel`). It works fine when I work with only one instance of my application. But when I use 2 and I try to drag objects from one and drop on the other, I get an exception when dropping:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Tymed non valide (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80040069 (DV_E_TYMED))'
```

and the two instances crash. My method to handle drop starts like this:

```
private void grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("fakeNode")) {
            var fakeNodeViewModel = (FakeNodeViewModel)e.Data.GetData("fakeNode");
```

and the program crash at var `fakeNodeViewModel = (FakeNodeViewModel)e.Data.GetData("fakeNode");`
I didn't find a lot about this. Does anyone know what happen and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate the `FakeNodeViewModel` class with the `System.SerializableAttribute` for it be COM serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class FakeNodeViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mm8 for your answer. Indeed, I had to add `[Serializable]` attribute to my `FakeNodeViewModel` class. Then I had to do my drag drop like this:

drag:

```
private void MoveFakeNode(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
                // Current mouse position
                var fakeNodeViewModel = (FakeNodeViewModel)((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
                var dataObject = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, fakeNodeViewModel);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop((DependencyObject)e.Source, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
```

drop:

```
private void grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable)) {
        // Get the fake node
        var fakeNodeViewModel =(FakeNodeViewModel)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
        ...
    }
}
```

And I was able to get my data from the other instance.